# Why does my lockscreen not update the bing image of the day?

Tags: 7.8, lock-screen, bing

I've recently updated my HTC Trophy 7 to Windows Phone 7.8. Now I am able to set the bing image of the day as my lockscreen wallpaper. However, it does not change regularly. Actually it has never changed until today, since I set it for the first time. My phone has WLAN access when I am at home during night and is connected through 3G when I am away. So it constatly has an internet connection.

Is this usual behaviour? How can I tell my phone to update the image daily?

Comment: Can you add provide us with more information of things you have tried? Such as restart phone, select different lock screen provider and then back.

Comment: Yes, I've restarted the phone and also switched the lock screen provider. After switching the provider back to bing, the new wallpaper get's shown. I will see, if it changed something, tomorrow. However I do not want to switch providers each and every day...

Comment: Hopefully switching it was enough to get the phone out of the stuck state that it was in. Good Luck!

Comment: Actually it really seemed to help. For a few days, the background image now got updated. However this appears pretty weird. I will keep an eye on this, for first...

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible that the background task that updates the lock screen has been turned off. There is an article at WPCentral that [details](http://www.wpcentral.com/fixing-problems-background-tasks-windows-phone) how to make sure background tasks are active for the apps you want.

Comment: There's no such background task in the list for me.