# Can I influence the time that the lockscreen updates?

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920, lock-screen, bing

After I already had problems with the lockscreen [on my old HTC 7 Trophy with the 7.8 update](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1890/why-does-my-lockscreen-not-update-the-bing-image-of-the-day), I finally switched over to a Lumia 920. Now I am facing a different problem with the bing-image-of-the-day-lockscreen: It does update, but it does this a few minutes before midnight... So I allways see the image of *yesterday* on my lockscreen, while I see the actual present image, when I hit the search-softkey.

I've already tried to switch off the lockscreen for a few days and switched it on in the morning, but this did not affect the behavior at all. I've also checked the list of background tasks, but I could not see any task for 'lockscreen', 'bing', and so on.

Is there any way to set the time my phone updates the lockscreen image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for those who are curious: I finally got this work with [WeatherFlow](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/weather-flow/9wzdncrdkl8t).

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change when the Bing wallpaper runs a wallpaper update on your phone but you can use other apps such as [Locksider](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/locksider/9wzdncrfj8cm), [PhotoStream](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/photostream/9wzdncrfhvnb) and [My 500px](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/my-500px/9nblggh0d7vv) to achieve what you are looking for.

Among the above apps, PhotoStream is free and the other two are not (you can try them for free).

Comment: All three apps apparently not support bing :/

Comment: They are your only options at this time

Answer (score 0):

There's another trick. I think it updates wallpaper exactly at the time you set your phone to use bing wallpaper. So you can try setting some custom wallpaper for a while and then, let's say at 7 am, change the setting to use Bing wallpaper. And since then, if I'm right, you'll get new picture every day at 7 am

Comment: I did so, but it did not work ;)